# Access Update/Pivot Query VBA/Query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

This is in continuity of the my previous question with two column, but here it is 4 column, I thought of editing my previous question, but i preferred to raise it as a new question!

```
   SAP   SAG   BAP  BAG
   One   One   One   One             
   One   Two   One   Two
   Two   One   Two   One        
   One   Two   One   Two 
   One   Two   One   Two
```

In this case, I am trying to get a result in combination of two columns, like below, i thought of writing a vba to calculate individually the SAP and BAP, but before that I wish to seek help, if there is any easy way to do this.

```
           SAG&BAG   
SAP&BAP   One    Two
One        2      6
Two        2      0
```

I am expecting the above result, Any suggestion?

*Since I am new to access and I am struggling to get my expected output many times, can some one tell me where i can find the help on query/vba syntax or some kind of tutorial? I googled for some hrs but cant find which one to focus...thanks in advance*

Answer (score 1):

SAP always = BAP and SAG always = BAG?

Consider:

Table1_UNION query

```
SELECT SAP AS [SAP_BAP], SAG AS [SAG_BAG] FROM Table1
UNION ALL SELECT BAP, BAG FROM Table1;
```

second query

```
TRANSFORM Count(Table1_UNION.SAG_BAG) AS CountOfSAG_BAG
SELECT Table1_UNION.SAP_BAP
FROM Table1_UNION
GROUP BY Table1_UNION.SAP_BAP
PIVOT Table1_UNION.SAG_BAG;
```

Comment: No! SAP not always = BAP and SAG not always = BAG....
But the values on all the field will be similar